# Скрипт не выводит в консоль переменную $RANDOM

Tags: linux, bash

Ubuntu 16.04

Выполняю `echo $RANDOM`, получаю число.
Если все запихиваю в скрипт, то в выводе пусто.

Скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAXCOUNT=10
count=1
while [ "$count" -le $MAXCOUNT ]
do
  echo $RANDOM
  count=$((count+1))
  echo $count
done
```

Получаю такой вывод:

[image: $random]

Comment: Запускайте через `bash`. Ведь `$RANDOM` - это именно его функция.

Comment: @mkkik оуу, щит. Вы мне сейчас глаза раскрыли, что "sh *.sh" это не просто команда на запуск скрипта, но еще и командная оболочка, которая выполняет. А почему в таком случае игнорируется #!/bin/bash ? P.S. оформите, пожалуйста. как ответ.

Comment: На заметку: более правильный шебанг — `#!/usr/bin/env bash` ибо будет работать не только в линуксе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для использования в скрипте случайного числа `$RANDOM`, за которым стоит вызов внутренней функции `bash`, естественно, надо использовать интерпретатор `bash`, а не `sh`. Это у вас и указано в шебанге (`#!/bin/bash`).

В вашем случае шебанг игнорируется, потому что явно указали командную оболочку (`sh`), в которой запускать скрипт.

Как использовать шебанг:

Присваиваем файлу со скриптом аттрибут исполняемого файла

```
 chmod +x create.sh
```

Запускаем на исполнение

```
 ./create.sh
```